# Read image blob from mysql and displaying it

Tags: php, mysql, image

I'm new to php,html and mysql so apologize my question.

I'm uploading an image to mysql ( this part work fine ), 
I'm now trying to read it and display it on my page.

Here is my code to save it to mysql

```
echo "<br>file selected run script";
echo "<br>file name : ".$_FILES['userfile']['name'];
echo "<br>file type : ".$_FILES['userfile']['type'];
echo "<br>file size : ".$_FILES['userfile']['size'];
$name = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$type = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];

$tmpName = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
echo "$tmpName";
$fp = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
$data = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
$data = addslashes($data);
fclose($fp);

$sql = "INSERT INTO images (image,name,type)
VALUES ('$data','$name','$type')";
$conn->exec($sql);
```

and it work.  I have an HTML file with  in it.

and loadimage.php is  :

$id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "id", FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    try     {

```
    /*** set the PDO error mode to exception ***/
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    /*** The sql statement ***/
    $sql = "SELECT image,type FROM images WHERE id='$id'";
    echo $sql;
            /*** prepare the sql ***/
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    /*** exceute the query ***/
    $stmt->execute(); 

    /*** set the fetch mode to associative array ***/
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    /*** set the header for the image ***/
    $array = $stmt->fetch();

    /*** check we have a single image and type ***/
    if(sizeof($array) == 2)
        {
        /*** set the headers and display the image ***/
        header("Content-type:".$array['type']);

        /*** output the image ***/
        echo $array['image'];
        }
    else
        {
        throw new Exception("Out of bounds Error");
        }
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
catch(Exception $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    }
```

else
        {
        echo 'Please use a real id number';
        }

It does connect to mysql, thats not the problem.

But chrome console give me the message :

**Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/jpeg: "http://xxxxxxxxxxxxx/loadimage.php?id=12".**

when trying to get my image id 12 ( all image give the same result .... )

Comment: you are not using prepared statements correctly so you are open to SQL injections

Comment: **WARNING**: When using PDO you should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) with placeholder values and supply any user data as separate arguments. In this code you have potentially severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Never use string interpolation or concatenation and instead use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and never put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly in your query. Refer to [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) for guidance with this and other problems.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that and I will solve that when my code will actualy work